# Please fill out the help center

Tags: support, status-completed, scope, help-center

Moderators, I request that you fill out [the What topics can I ask about? page](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We have already [started a discussion about it](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/what-should-the-help-center-read-about-on-topic-and-off-topic-questions), which did not attract very many opinions; I believe that [Phil Frost's complete answer](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/197/76) is quite a lot better than nothing, which is what we have now, and I have not seen anyone object to it.

Comment: I think Michael was just waiting on a little more consensus, but most of the deeply engaged users of the site tend to just enjoy themselves on the main site, reading to their heart's content, without coming to meta. We should be good to go ahead and update the help center now.

Comment: @TimPost Indeed. I've done it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copied [Phil Frost's answer](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/197/29), with a few slight modifications, to the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

Comment: Thank you. Should perhaps the other question also be marked status-completed now?

Comment: You're right @KevinReidAG6YO -- I missed that one. Thanks for pointing it out!